# Android Studio creates duplicate apps

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run my project to test it, Android Studio ends up creating two of the same apps on my emulator and phone.

Why is that?

EDIT: The reason was because of the PebbleKit creating another app.

Answer (score 8):

Another possibility is that if you have multiple activities with:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

in both of their manifest files. This can create multiple icons in the app drawer.

Answer (score 0):

check your gradle build files, it may be creating multiple flavors or build types, and deploying them for testing.